# I am using okhttp in my android application. Is there any way to prevent duplicate requests from getting executed?

Tags: android, okhttp

I am using okhttp in my android application. Is there any way to prevent duplicate requests from getting executed? Suppose if http://mob.xyz.com/search-products is already being executed , if same request is executed again then it should be cancelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. We’ve got a [big feature planned](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/607) to add this, but it won’t be ready for several months.